# Android Programming how can i convert or cast widget to java string

Tags: java, android, casting

I am basically getting the value of a Textview in Android and then hashing that Text but I am getting an exception **String can not be converted into Android.Widget.TextView** This is my simple code

```
TextView mypassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    mypassword= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
    mypassword= BCrypt.hashpw(mypassword,BCrypt.gensalt(12));
}
```

The hashpw takes the following parameters hashpw(Java.lang.String, String)
I been trying to cast this to no avail any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `String` value of the text in a `TextView` by calling `getText().toString()` on the `TextView`.